# Can output of final classification FC layer can be negative?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am getting final output Fc layer values all negative? Can it be negative? my final layer looks like(bnorm->dropout->linear)

Comment: Yes, why not? You don't have an activation such as ReLU that will make it only non-negative.

Comment: thanks @GilPinsky, my main reason to ask this question is that I have fused Bnorm and linear (learnable parameter) before fusing ,final layer output was having positive and negative values but after fusing i am getting all values negative including fused weights

Comment: No problem. If you provide code and results it will be easier to help.